# Extremely high CPU usage and laggy behaviour with 3D-acceleration in Linux Mint (Virtual Box) but not with software rendering

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gpu

I'm currently trying to get Linux Mint 18.2 to work in Oracle Virtual Box.

What have I done so far:

Installed VBoxAdditions 5.0.40 or 5.1.26 (first one through apt-get, second one through the VirtualBox-Guest-Additions .iso itself). That does not mean that I installed them concurrently, after each try I removed the packages with following method:

Completely removed everything about VirtualBox with `apt-get purge virtualbox*` and `apt-get purge Virtualbox*`. The Synaptic Package Manager showed a total of 0 installed virtualbox packages after that.

I found several tests that show 3D-Acceleration is enabled:

```
$/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

OpenGL vendor string:   Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Chromium 1.9

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

and:

```
$inxi -G | grep Renderer      

GLX Renderer: Chromium GLX Version: 2.1 Chromium 1.9
```

and:

```
$glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Chromium 1.9
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.30 - Build 20.19.15.4531
OpenGL extensions:
```

A quick benchmark showed following result:

```
$glxgears

1242 frames in 5.0 seconds = 248.234 FPS
1280 frames in 5.0 seconds = 255.818 FPS
1209 frames in 5.0 seconds = 241.569 FPS
1107 frames in 5.0 seconds = 221.356 FPS
1243 frames in 5.0 seconds = 248.558 FPS
1167 frames in 5.0 seconds = 233.303 FPS
1233 frames in 5.0 seconds = 246.507 FPS
1140 frames in 5.0 seconds = 227.865 FPS
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 71944 requests (71944 known processed) with 0 events remaining
```

I have to note that the whole system became extremely sluggish and unusable during that benchmark.

In general everything seems to "work". The usual things associated with Guest-Additions (copy-and-paste, resizing the windows, etc.) seem to work. Browsing with Firefox is extremely smooth, even smoother than browsing with Chrome on my Host machine.

But as soon as 3D-accelerated things have to be drawn (it seems like the cinnamon-menu is 3D-accelerated too), my CPU usage on the host machine rises from 0-10% to 40-80% and in general everything becomes extremely laggy. I'm just talking about TYPING single characters in the search bar on the cinnamon start menu. Whenever I type something in Firefox or other entering masks, it's extremely smooth. But as soon as I do that in the menu or use other 3D-accelerated things, it seems like the drawing of the 2D-desktop slows down to 5-10 FPS.

That are my settings in VirtualBox:

```
3072 MB RAM
2 processor cores
100% CPU ratio
PAE/NX enabled
VT-x enabled
128 MB (max) VRAM
3D-acceleration enabled
```

It occurs at both of my computers with following hardware:

```
i7-4500U
8 GB DDR3 RAM
Intel HD Graphics
```

and:

```
i5-2400 OC to 4,4 GHz
8 GB DDR3 RAM 
GTX 1060
```

I don't think my hardware is the problem here.

I tried to not use the 3D-acceleration, namely using software-rendering. On a restart, the message that I am currently using software-renering and therefore the UI can seem sluggish appeared.

But quite the contrary. The menu is smoother (NOT smooth. But I would guess something around 15 FPS) and the benchmark (glxgears) showed something around 650 FPS, so about 3x of that we achieved before. So clearly there is something not working correctly with the hardware acceleration.